# How to get date difference using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to get data difference like years, month, date etc. like wise. this is my code

```
time1 =new Date(1988, 1, 8, 23, 23, 0, 0);
time2 = new Date();

difference = time2 - time1;
document.write(difference);
```

this returns something like this `782215145373`. I think milliseconds. so how I get that difference like years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds wise.

Actually in here I tried this way to get month difference

```
month_diff = time2.getMonth()-time1.getMonth();
```

but it gives 9 but correct answer should be 10. please help me why?

Comment: Yeah, that's millis. Divide it by 1000 and get diffrence in seconds. Divide by 60 000 and get difference in minutes. You get the idea. And use search! http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224854/704503

Comment: Look at this http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/

Comment: thanks, I thought javascript priovde inbuilt function for that

Comment: `diffInDays = 0|(time2 - time1) * 1.16e-8`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 //your calculated difference in milliseconds
  var diff_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;

  //take out milliseconds
  diff_ms = diff_ms/1000;

  var seconds = Math.floor(diff_ms % 60);

  diff_ms = difference_ms/60; 
  var minutes = Math.floor(diff_ms % 60);

  diff_ms = diffms/60; 

  var hours = Math.floor(diff_ms % 24);

  var days = Math.floor(diff_ms/24);
```